# Replace function converting © to Â©

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to replace a string which is having `©` using VBScript. However, after replcement its getting converted as `Â©`.

Tried using UTF-8, but didn't help.

```
Set objectFile = objFSOWrite.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1)
strText = objectFile.ReadAll
objectFile.Close

Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type = 2 'text
stream.Charset = "UTF-8"

strNewText = Replace(strText, myLine, valueToUpdate)
stream.LoadFromFile strNewText
Set objectFile = objFSOWrite.OpenTextFile(filePath, 2, True, True)
objectFile.WriteLine strNewText
stream.Close
objectFile.Close
```

`©` is getting replaced with `Â©`.

Comment: `Â© ` (hexadecimal sequence `0xC2`,`0xA9` is UTF-8 representation of the character `©`  _Copyright Sign_.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried above code, however script is replacing as it is. There is no change in output.

Comment: Please could you [edit] the question to  elaborate your [mcve]? Maybe comparing  pained parts of input and output files (if possible, add a hexadecimal view as well) could help. And where the `valueToUpdate` comes from? `VbScript`, as is, do not understand  `UTF-8`.

Comment: Below is test code, I wrote.

Comment: Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

Dim objStream, strData
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 2 'text
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile("c:\replace\PtStrings.properties")
strData = objStream.ReadText()


Dim objStream1
Set objStream1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream1.Type = 2 'text
objStream1.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream1.Open
objStream1.WriteText UCase("©")
objStream1.SaveToFile "c:\replace\PtStrings_1.properties", 2

Comment: Please no not post code snippets in comments (we can't format code properly there). Use [edit] button rather.